# Bedeutung von „grenzwertig!“

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

So, ich habe ein paar Bedeutungen und Beispiele aus den Wörterbüchern gesammelt, von denen mir keins wirklich was über dieses Wort sagt. Ich bin mir sicher, dass die Experten ggf. Muttersprachler hier einen besseren Hinweis zum Wort anbieten könnten.

Aus dem  [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/grenzwertig)

> *Bedeutung*. Gerade noch im Bereich des Positiven, Erträglichen o. Ä. liegend.
>
> z.B.
>   1. sein Humor ist echt grenzwertig
>   2. eine grenzwertige Belastung

Oder [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/grenzwertig) meint, *grenzwertig* sei *kaum noch tolerabel*.

> *Beispiele*:
>     1.  „Die Athleten arbeiten gerne mit Psychotricks – manche sind erlaubt, andere grenzwertig.“

- Ist aber *grenzwertig* nicht etwa eben das Gegenteil? (d.h. unerträglich?) Könnte jemand mit Beispielen erklären?

Comment: If you want a 1:1 translation: "borderline" describes the word pretty accurately.

Comment: Nur falls du es nicht wusstest... das mathematische Limit (Lim.) heißt in Deutsch "Grenzwert". Ebenso gesetzliche "limits" für Messwerte.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wie ist eine Grenze zu verstehen? Gehört die Grenze zwischen A und B zu A? Oder zu B? Zu beiden gleichzeitig?

Genau das Dilemma beschreibt der Begriff "grenzwertig" - etwas, was *gerade noch so* im zugehörigen Bereich liegt. Oder eben gerade außerhalb, je nach Standpunkt.

Meist (aber nicht ausschließlich) wird er benutzt, um zu sagen, dass etwas noch als erlaubt oder in Ordnung zu betrachten ist, wie in Deinen Beispielen.

Comment: Tja, ich dachte bisher auch, dass `grenzwertig` sich auf der erlaubten Seite befände, aber da habe ich nicht mit Eltern und Leitung an meiner Schule gerechnet, für die `grenzwertig` schon sehr weit hinter der Grenze im unerlaubten Bereich liegt.

Comment: Um justiziabel zu sein, muss natürlich klar geregelt sein, ob die Grenze zu A oder B gehört. Mathematisch gesehen, ist es erstmal egal, ob die Grenze dazu gehört, oder nicht. Man unterscheidet einfach beide Fälle nach `offen` oder `abgeschlossen` bzw. untersucht die `Schärfe` einer Grenze. `grenzwertig` würde in diesem Sinne nur bedeuten, in der Nähe der Grenze zu liegen.

Comment: Natürlich ist mathematisch immer anzugeben, wie die Intervallgrenzen zu behandeln sind, ebenso juristisch, aber genau die Tatsache dass der Begriff einer ausführlichen Definition im Einzelfall bedarf, zeigt, wie die Alltagssprache eine Grenze warnimmt... Und wo *genau* eine Grenze verläuft, unterscheidet sich oft genug eben von Betrachter zu Betrachter, nicht nur zwischen Staaten :-)

Comment: @Toscho Entschuldigung, aber eigentlich sind *offen* und *abgeschlossen* halt überhaupt keine mathematische Antonyme (d.h. "`A` abgeschlossen" bedeutet nicht "`A` nicht offen"). Es gibt Mengen die gleichzeitig abgeschlossen und offen sind (die mit der diskreten Topologie versehnte Räume bittet jede (Teil)Menge Beispiele an), z.B. die leere Menge. Daher würde ich nicht sagen, dass solche Eigenschaften als 'unterschiedliche Fälle' betrachten werden können :)

Comment: @c.p. Ich wollte den Rahmen jetzt nicht auf abstraktere Varianten von `offen` und `abgeschlossen` ausbreiten. In Topologien kannst du mit beiden Begriffen alles möglich anstellen, das nichts mehr mit Sprache zu tun hat.

Comment: @Toscho: Beim Verhalten kann es sein, dass man von jmd. (Schüler/Lehrer?) erwartet, dass er sich gar nicht in den grenzwertigen Bereich begibt oder wenn, dass es eine Ausnahme ist. Vielleicht geht es um regelmäßiges Ausloten des grenzwertigen Bereichs?

Answer (score 6):

»Grenzwertig« ist ein Wert, der so nahe an der Grenze liegt, dass (innerhalb der Mess-Unsicherheit) nicht klar gesagt werden kann, ob er darüber oder darunter liegt. Daher ist es ganz natürlich, dass es über grenzwertige Ereignisse gegensätzliche Meinungen darüber gibt, auf welcher Seite der Grenze das Ereignis einzuordnen ist.

Verschärft wird das dadurch, dass es hier häufig auch keine konkrete oder offizielle Grenze gibt, sondern dass das persönliche Empfinden jedes Einzelnen zur Grenzziehung herangezogen wird. Etwas, das Frau Mayer bereits als unerträglich oder inakzeptabel erachtet, mag für den Herrn Müller durchaus noch in Ordnung sein. Aber beide werden sich möglicherweise darauf einigen können, dass das Objekt ihrer Betrachtungen grenzwertig ist.

Answer (score 2):

Ich meine, *grenzwertig* liegt meistens am Rande des positiven Bereiches (wie es der Duden sagt).

Im Zusammenhang mit einem Gesetz stellt das Gesetz den "positiven Bereich" dar. In diesem Zusammenhang ist es (wie nach Wiktionary) kaum tolerabel. In deinem letzten Beispiel sind Psycho-Tricks noch gesetzlich erlaubt, aber dennoch schlecht angesehen.

Es wird oft benutzt, um zu sagen, dass etwas zwar erlaubt ist, aber dennoch negativ ist.

*Grenzwertig* ist ein diplomatisches Wort, da es "schwer nachweisbare" Kritik erlaubt. So kann man *grenzwertig* deutlich negativ benutzen, ohne dass diese negative Aussage bemängelt werden kann.

Vergleich: Die Aussage "Er hat sich stets bemüht" ist ein positiver Satz (und damit auch erlaubt, wenn Negatives verboten ist), dennoch ist die Bedeutung äußerst negativ.

> Dein Humor ist echt grenzwertig.

Dies sagt, dass man den Humor der angesprochenen Person noch erträglich findet (man möchte sie ja nicht beleidigen), aber er ist kurz davor, schlecht zu sein.
Eigentlich sagt dies aus, dass der Humor schlecht ist oder dass man den letzten Witz nicht lustig fand.

Comment: Ob ein Witz lustig ist oder nicht, beschreibt man nicht mit dem Begriff der Grenzwertigkeit. Der grenzwertige Witz verletzt die guten Sitten in der ein oder anderen Richtung - er könnte zotig sein, Ekel erregend, politisch inakzeptabel, die Pietät verletzend, u. dgl. und man könnte, wenn er gut ist, von der Pointe überrascht, diesen sehr witzig finden aber das Machen eines solchen Witzes in der Situation inakzeptabel finden. Ich kenne einige grenzwertige Witze, aber wenn ihnen das lustige Element abgeht halte ich es nicht für grenzwertigen Humor, sondern gar nicht für Humor.

Answer (score 0):

In dem Beispiel *sein Humor ist echt grenzwertig* handelt es sich um einen umgangssprachlichen Euphemismus, der zurzeit in Mode ist. Wer das so sagt, meint in Wirklichkeit, daß er den Humor desjenigen mies findet.

Comment: Auch nicht zwingend. Leute, die grenzwertigen Humor mögen, wissen i.d.R., dass er grenzwertig ist und genießen ihn gerade deswegen. Das hält sie nicht davon ab diesen als solchen zu bezeichnen.