# "finde ich langweilig" vs "ist mir langweilig" vs "ist für mich langweilig"

Tags: difference, usage

> (a) Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, finde ich langweilig.

Kann man auch die Folgenden sagen? Hätten sie dieselbe Bedeutung?

> (b) Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, ist mir langweilig.
>
> (c) Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, ist für mich langweilig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der erste Satz ist auf jeden Fall korrekt:

> Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, finde ich langweilig.

Die beiden anderen wird man von einem Muttersprachler kaum hören, wobei zumindest der dritte  (*… ist für mich langweilig*) wenigstens grammatisch richtig ist. Stilistisch ist er [grenzwertig](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20204/bedeutung-von-grenzwertig).

Den zweiten Satz halte ich für falsch, wobei ich nicht ausschließen kann, dass man ihn so interpretieren kann, dass er doch noch als richtig gelten kann. Verwenden würde ich ihn jedoch nicht.

---

Die folgenden Sätze haben dieselbe Bedeutung wie *… finde ich langweilig*:

> Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, halte ich für langweilig.
>   Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, erscheint mir langweilig.

Fast dasselbe sagen die beiden folgenden Sätze aus:

> Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, langweilt mich.
>   Beim Machen/Erledigen der Hausaufgaben empfinde ich Langeweile.

Der Unterschied ist folgender: In den ersten Beispielen bringt der Sprecher seine persönliche Einschätzung zu Ausdruck. Zu dieser Einschätzung könnte es auch gekommen sein, ohne jemals selbst eine Hausaufgabe gemacht zu haben. Er könnte andere dabei beobachtet haben, und aus dieser Beobachtung einen Schluss gezogen haben.

Bei den beiden unteren Sätzen bringt der Sprecher jedoch seine persönliche Erfahrung zum Ausdruck. Diese Sätze kann nur jemand sagen, der tatsächlich wenigstens einmal Hausaufgaben gemacht und dabei Langeweile verspürt hat, und nun diese Erfahrung in die Zukunft extrapoliert.

---

Der folgende Satz lässt die persönliche Position des Sprechers zumindest formal ganz weg und steht in der Form einer allgemein gültigen Behauptung:

> Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, ist langweilig.

Aber obwohl die formale Aussage eine augenscheinlich objektive und allgemein gültige ist, spiegelt sie natürlich dennoch die persönliche und sehr subjektive Meinung des Sprechers wider. Insofern besteht zwischen diesem Satz und den weiter oben stehenden durchaus eine enge inhaltliche Verwandtschaft.

---

Noch erwähnen möchte ich, dass es in Österreich und im Süden Deutschlands das Adjektiv »fad« als Synonym für »langweilig« gibt. Er gibt aber kein entsprechendes Synonym für das Verb »langweilen« und auch nicht für das Nomen »Langeweile«. Daher sind in diesen Regionen auch diese Varianten möglich:

> Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, finde ich fad.
>   Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, halte ich für fad.
>   Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, erscheint mir fad.
>   Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, ist fad.

Die *fad*en Varianten sind zwar korrektes österreichisches Hochdeutsch, gelten aber auch in Österreich als stilistisch weniger reizvoll als die *langweilig*en Sätze.

---

**Nachtrag zu den von Grantwalzer vorgeschlagenen Wörtern *fadisieren* und *Fadesse*:**

Beide Wörter sind, wie auch *fad*, Austriazismen und mit diesem Wort verwandt.

**(sich) fadisieren**
Das Wort bedeutet zwar *(sich) langweilen*, wird aber nur reflexiv, also gemeinsam mit einem Reflexivpronomen verwendet:

> Lisa langweilt sich. = Lisa fadisiert sich.
>   Wir langweilen uns. = Wir fadisieren uns.

Eine transitive Verwendung ist aber nicht möglich:

> Die Bahnfahrt langweilt mich. (keine identische Konstruktion mit *fadisieren* möglich)
>   Die Hausaufgaben zu machen, langweilt mich. (keine identische Konstruktion mit *fadisieren* möglich)

Siehe auch: http://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/mich_fadisieren.htm

**Fadesse**
Dieses Wort bedeutet zwar *Langeweile*, und kann grammatisch gleich verwendet werden, drückt aber stilistisch etwas anderes aus.

Wiktionary sagt zwar, *Fadesse* habe zwei Bedeutungen, nämlich *Langeweile* und *geziertes Gehabe*, was auch richtig ist, sagt aber nicht dazu, dass das Wort immer beide Bedeutungen zugleich hat. Es ist also nicht so, das man einen Satz bilden könnte, in dem *Fadesse* ausschließlich in der Bedeutung *Langeweile* verwendet werden kann, ohne zugleich auch *geziertes Gehabe* zu bedeuten.

Es ist vielmehr so, dass *Fadesse* etwas wie *gezierte/snobistische Langeweile* bedeutet. Mit diesem Wort schwingen immer Hochnäsigkeit und Arroganz mit.

Ein Schüler, der sich beim Machen seiner Hausaufgabe fadisiert, empfindet üblicherweise keine Fadesse, sondern stinknormale Langeweile. Der Gebrauch des Wortes *Fadesse* wäre allerdings dann angebracht, wenn zugleich zum Ausdruck gebracht werden soll, dass derselbe Schüler sich nicht nur langweilt, sondern es auch als unter seiner Würde empfindet, sich mit Hausübungen zu beschäftigen.

---

**Ergänzung zu *fad*:**
Johann Nestroy schrieb 1837 die Komödie »Das Haus der Temperamente«. In diesem Haus wohnen vier Familien, welche die vier Temperamente *Choleriker*, *Sanguiniker*, *Melancholiker* und *Phlegmatiker* repräsentieren. Die phlegmatische Familie trägt den Namen *Fad*.
(Die anderen Familiennamen in diesem Stück sind: cholerisch = Braus, sanguinisch = Froh, melancholisch = Trüb)

Answer (score 0):

Dein zweiter Satz erscheint mir grammatikalisch falsch, was nicht ausschließt, dass er regional oder in älterer Sprache auftaucht, das weiß ich nicht. Möglich ist aber:

> Die Hausaufgaben zu machen langweilt mich.